# Delete a file if the third colum of the one line of the file is 0?

Tags: bash, awk

I have 100 files named file1.dat file2.dat,...file100.dat.
Each of them looks like

```
#  step    population   probability
1   0.00000000       0.00000000    
2   0.00000000       0.00000000
```

where the values of the second and third column for lines may be different.

I want to delete these file among the 100 files, if **the value of third column of the second line is 0**.(condition)
First,I tried in bash to find out these file which satisfying the condition is met

```
    n='0.00000000' 
    col='$3'
    e=0.0000001
    for i in file*.dat
    do
     awk -v col=$col 'NR==2{ if(col<e) print col}' > $n
     echo $n
    done
```

It does not print anyting. Does there any better ideas to do this?

Comment: You aren't using the filename ($i) in the awk command anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to delete these file among the 100 files, if the value of third column of the second line is 0

You can use:

```
for file in file*.dat; do
   awk 'NR==2{exit ($3 != 0)}' "$file" && echo rm "$file"
done
```

When satisfied with the results remove `echo` before `rm`.

Comment: You could probably shorten `awk` to `awk 'NR==2{exit ($3 != 0)}'` That will also make script faster for large files.

Comment: `$f `Should be `$file`.

Comment: Because the parameter to `exit` is a single unsigned byte, this may not work in all situations. Modifying the code to work with files where the value coud be a very small float, or a multiple of 256 for a different failure scenario, shoud not be too hard once you understand this peculiarity.

Comment: Good and valid point @tripleee, `$3 != 0` is safer check (edited)